# Multi-tenancy with dynamic Postgresql database in spring-boot

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, multi-tenant

I'm currently facing an issue with integrating multi-tenancy in my spring-boot project.

Here is the situation: I'm linking my spring boot project with a DB source which is Postgresql: one of the database of the pool is known, the "master", which is the default DB the spring-boot project will connect to. The other DB of the pool are unknown, and I want to be able to switch the DB connection to them during the app runtime with an API call. In a **TablesController**, I created a GET METHOD getting in the query a parameter "envname" and tries to switch the current DB connected to the one with the envname, and to return the list of its tables.

I tried [this tutorial](http://stuartingram.com/2016/10/02/spring-boot-schema-based-multi-tenancy/), but i can't find why it's not working. Here's my code:

#### pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

#### application.properties

```
# General properties
server.port = 9090

# Hibernate properties
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.hibernate.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.tenant_identifier_resolver= com.example.myproject.util.CurrentTenantIdentifierResolverImp

# Postgresql properties
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/master
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.datasource.initialize=true
spring.datasource.continue-on-error=true
```

#### TenantContext

```
public class TenantContext {

  final public static String DEFAULT_TENANT = "master";

  private static ThreadLocal<String> currentTenant = new ThreadLocal<String>()
  {
    @Override
    protected String initialValue() {
      return DEFAULT_TENANT;
    }
  };

  public static void setCurrentTenant(String tenant) {
    currentTenant.set(tenant);
  }

  public static String getCurrentTenant() {
    return currentTenant.get();
  }

  public static void clear() {
    currentTenant.remove();
  }
}
```

#### TablesController

```
@RestController
public class TablesController {

@Autowired
GetTablesName getTablesNames;

@Autowired
DataSource dataSource;

@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@Autowired
private ApplicationContext appContext;

@Autowired
public BackXPressConfig backXPressConfig;

@GetMapping("/{envname}/tables")
public ResponseEntity<?> getTablesByEnv(@PathVariable("envname") String envname){
    TenantContext.setCurrentTenant(envname);    
    try {
        System.out.println(TenantContext.getCurrentTenant());
        Object o = JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(dataSource, getTablesNames);
        System.out.println(o);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(o);
    } catch (MetaDataAccessException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

#### TenantIdentifier

```
@Component
public class TenantIdentifier implements CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver{

  @Override
  public String resolveCurrentTenantIdentifier() {
    return TenantContext.getCurrentTenant();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean validateExistingCurrentSessions() {
    return true;
  }
}
```

#### TenantInterceptor

```
@Component
public class TenantInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

@Override
public void postHandle(
  HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView)
      throws Exception {
TenantContext.clear();
  }
}
```

#### HibernateConfig

```
@Configuration
public class HibernateConfig {    
@Autowired
private JpaProperties jpaProperties;

@Bean
public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
   return new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
}

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource,
  MultiTenantConnectionProvider multiTenantConnectionProviderImpl,
  CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver currentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl) {

   Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
   properties.putAll(jpaProperties.getProperties());
   properties.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT, MultiTenancyStrategy.DATABASE);
   properties.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT_CONNECTION_PROVIDER, multiTenantConnectionProviderImpl);
   properties.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT_IDENTIFIER_RESOLVER, currentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl);

   LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
   em.setDataSource(dataSource);
   em.setPackagesToScan("com.example.myproject");
   em.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
   em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);
   return em;
   }
}
```

#### GetTables

```
@Service
public class GetTablesName implements DatabaseMetaDataCallback {

public List<String> processMetaData(DatabaseMetaData metaData) throws SQLException {
    ResultSet rawDataSet = metaData.getTables(metaData.getUserName(), null, null, new String[]{"TABLE"});
    List<String> listTable = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (rawDataSet.next()) {
        listTable.add(rawDataSet.getString(3));
    }
    return listTable;
}

}
```

#### MultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl

```
@Component
public class MultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl implements MultiTenantConnectionProvider {  
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 6246085840652870138L;

  @Autowired
  private DataSource dataSource;

  @Override
  public Connection getAnyConnection() throws SQLException {
    return dataSource.getConnection();
  }

  @Override
  public void releaseAnyConnection(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
    connection.close();
  }

  @Override
  public Connection getConnection(String tenantIdentifier) throws SQLException {
    final Connection connection = getAnyConnection();
    try {
      connection.createStatement().execute( "USE " + tenantIdentifier );
    }
    catch ( SQLException e ) {
      throw new HibernateException(
          "Could not alter JDBC connection to specified schema [" + tenantIdentifier + "]",
          e
          );
    }
    return connection;
  }

  @Override
  public void releaseConnection(String tenantIdentifier, Connection connection) throws SQLException {
    try {
      connection.createStatement().execute( "USE " + tenantIdentifier );
    }
    catch ( SQLException e ) {
      throw new HibernateException(
      "Could not alter JDBC connection to specified schema [" + tenantIdentifier + "]",
      e
      );
    }
    connection.close();
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
  @Override
  public boolean isUnwrappableAs(Class unwrapType) {
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public <T> T unwrap(Class<T> unwrapType) {
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean supportsAggressiveRelease() {
    return true;
  }

}
```

Comment: Do you have a `preHandle` implementation as part of the `TenantInterceptor` so that the tenant context is established on receiving the request in your application.

Comment: Thanks Saravanan for your comment. I choosed not to implement a preHandle, because some of my API's method are not using the multi tenancy. But I may be the problem with my code, I may look at it !